# Set cookie in request from jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I have an client and server project (jersey Rest api) , and make a rest call from (localhost/client/) to (localhost/server)

And i need to set a cookie in resource.

```
@path(authenticate)
@POST
public Response authenticate(authData auth){
  set cookie in (localhost/server)   ---> need to set a cookie here
  return Response;
}
```

How can i accomplish this situation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Response.ResponseBuilder` has a `cookie` method for setting cookies in the response. It accepts a [NewCookie](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.7/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/NewCookie.html) object for setting the name, value etc.

Comment: I need to set a cookie in localhost/server domain. I already tried Response.ok().cookie().build(); But it not working

Comment: But you need to use `Response.ok().cookie(new NewCookie(name, value)).build();`, otherwise you will not set any cookies in the response.

Comment: Response.ok().entity(someData).cookie(new NewCookie("token", GetRandomString(12),"/restServer","localhost",1,null,240000,false)).build(); This is what my code, Is there any mistake i made